Why does the book say $\frac{-3\pm i\cdot \sqrt{7}}{4}$?
Equation given:
$2z^2 + 3z + 2 = 0$
Attempt:
$2z^2 + 3z + 2 = 0$
$\frac{2z^2}{2} + \frac{3}{2}z + \frac{2}{2} = 0$
$z^2 + \frac{3}{2}z + 1 = 0$
$z = \frac{-3}{2} \pm \sqrt{\frac{(\frac{3}{2})^2 - 4(1)(2)}{2(2)}}$
$z = \frac{-3}{2} \pm \sqrt{\frac{(\frac{3}{2})^2 - 8}{4}}$
$z = \frac{-3}{2} \pm \sqrt{\frac{2,25 - 8}{4}}$
$z = \frac{-3\pm i \cdot \sqrt{5,75}}{4}$
My Answer is wrong, not sure, how they get 7 here.
According to the book:
$\frac{-3\pm i\cdot \sqrt{7}}{4}$

The discriminant is $b^2-4ac$, which is here $3^2-4 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 = -7$, so you should have made some calculation error.

In your application of the quadratic formula, you appear to continue to treat the lead coefficient as $2$ even though you have divided through by it.  That is, you are inconsistent.

Aha, so, I should've kept it as original. Damn.

Also: don't convert common fractions to decimals. $1.5$ is just one decimal place of accuracy. $3/2$ is exact.

No. Dividing through by $2$ was fine. But when you applied the quadratic formula, you have "(2)" in two places, and each of these should be "(1)" (or simply deleted). That would then lead to the correct result.

@Dominique, I am a bit lost here. So, I shouldn't have it like I have written?
$\frac{3}{2}^2$ ?

Dominique was computing the discriminant of the equation before you divided through by 2. That explains the difference.

The point is to be consistent.  If you divide by $2$, then the coefficients are $\left(1, \frac 32, 1\right)$.  If you don't divide by $2$, then they are $(2,3,2)$.  You can work with either of these, but having chosen one, stick with it.

@lulu, so, if I chose to go with the former, and not the latter, how would I then proceed?

If you divide by $2$, then, in the notation of the quadratic formula, we have $(a,b,c)=\left(1, \frac 32, 1\right)$.  So then the roots would be $\frac {-\frac 32\pm \sqrt {\left(\frac 32\right)^2-4\times 1\times 1}}{2}$

@lulu, how do you handle the factions in this context?

Factor out $\sqrt 4=2$.  That is, $\sqrt {\left(\frac 32\right)^2-4\times 1\times 1}=\frac 12\times \sqrt {9-4\times 4}=\frac 12\times \sqrt {-7}$

@lulu, that's way too fast, I am already lost.

If you find the arithmetic of fractions too error prone, then avoid them.  Don't divide through by $2$.  Then we get $x=\frac {-3\pm \sqrt {9-16}}4$ directly.  It's not a question or right or wrong, either method is fine.  But I think it's fair to say that dividing through by $2$ makes the arithmetic harder, not easier.


$ 2z^2 + 3z + 2 = 0 $ (The original statement).

$ \frac{2z^2 + 3z + 2 = 0}{2} $ (Divide everything by 2).

$ z^2 + \frac{3}{2}z + 1 = 0 $ (Result of the division can now be solved by the quadratic equation).

Quadratic formula applies for an equation in this form: $ ax^2 + bx + c = 0 $


Note in your case: $(a = 1, b = \frac{3}{2}, c = 1)$.

The quadratic formula shall apply such that: $ x = \frac{-b   \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a} $

$ z = \frac{-\frac{3}{2} \pm \sqrt{(\frac{3}{2})^2 - 4}}{2}$ (In your example).

$ z = \frac{-\frac{3}{2} \pm \sqrt{-\frac{7}{4}}}{2}$ (The square of three halves minus four is negative seven fourths).

$ z = \frac{-\frac{3}{2} \pm \frac{i\sqrt{7}}{2}}{2}$ (The square root of four is two and the square root of negative seven is i times the square root of seven).


Then since both terms in the numerator are already being divided by 2 anyways just combine it with the big denominator to make 4 like so:

$ z = \frac{-3 \pm i\sqrt{7}}{4}$


Hi, thanks. How do you go from: Step: 6 to 7 here?

You had 2,25 - 8 in your original example. It should have been 2,25 - 4. And 2,25 - 4 is the same as -7 divided by 4.
